# How to resize Images using PIL in a folder in python

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am using PIL/Python to resize the images in a folder . After resizing the images I want to save them again in the same folder with the same name but I am having error **cannot write mode RGBA as JPEG**

**there are multiple formats of images inside the folder**

this is the code which is used to resize the images

```
path = "data/images/"
dirs = os.listdir( path )

def resize():
    for item in dirs:
        if os.path.isfile(path+item):
            im = Image.open(path+item)
            f, e = os.path.splitext(path+item)
            imResize = im.resize((200,200), Image.ANTIALIAS)
            imResize.save(f, 'JPEG', quality=90)

resize()
```

this is the error I am having

```
cannot write mode RGBA as JPEG
```

Comment: maybe it is PNG and you should save it back as PNG, not JPEG - especially that you want to save with the same name. Display its name to see its extension. Maybe if you remove "JPEG" from `save()` it will use extension to recognize format and save it correctly. Or you will have to do it manuall - recognize extension and use correct option in `save()`.

Comment: PNG images can have an alpha (transparency) channel, whereas JPEG images cannot. If you open a PNG with alpha and try and save it as JPEG, you will get the message *'Cannot write RGBA as JPEG'*. You have 2 choices, either discard the alpha channel (which is unlikely to be a good idea) or save in PNG mode to preserve it - do this by retaining the original file's extension.

Answer (score 0):

Try:-

```
f = "apple.png"
im = Image.open(path+item)
im = im.convert("RGB") 
imResize = im.resize((200,200), Image.ANTIALIAS)
imResize.save(f, quality=90)
```

We removed the alpha channel from the image, and converted the color space to `RGB` only.  As most file formats support a image with RGB color space, I don't think errors will still continue to exist.

Don't explicitly define the output format of all input images as `.jpeg`,  rather let PIL determine it by looking at the file's extension.

**P.S.:-** Don't use this method if transparency of the image is taken into account(alpha channel),  as this method will get rid of the alpha channel of the image.

Answer (score 0):

To resize images I always have used `.thumbnail`. It's easy to use and it simply works.
To keep the data of the colors and the alpha, the solution brought by [Vasu Deo.S](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9042078/vasu-deo-s) works well and it's the one I am using on my script.

You need to save your images in `.png` instead of `.jpeg` to avoid the error of the alpha channel.

So here's your code edited that actually works.

```
path = "data/images/"
dirs = os.listdir( path )

def resizeImages():
    for item in dirs:
        if os.path.isfile(path+item):
            im = Image.open(path+item)
            im = im.convert('RGBA')

            size = 200, 200

            imResize.thumbnail(size)

            f, e = os.path.splitext(path+item)
            imResize.save(f+'.png')
```

Note that this, will need to be saved as `.png`. If you want to save as a `.jpeg` image, you must get rid of the alpha channel using this:

```
path = "data/images/"
dirs = os.listdir( path )

def resizeImages():
    for item in dirs:
        if os.path.isfile(path+item):
            im = Image.open(path+item)
            im = im.convert('RGBA')

            data = np.array(im)
            red, green, blue, alpha = data.T

            alpha_areas = (red == 0) & (blue == 0) & (green == 0) & (alpha == 0) # set alpha to 0
            data[..., :-1][alpha_areas.T] = (255,255,255)
            im = Image.fromarray(data)

            size = 200, 200

            imResize = im.thumbnail(size)

            f, e = os.path.splitext(path+item)
            imResize.save(f+'.png')
```

Comment: I believe the problem exists in the `save()`,  rather then the method used to resize the image.

Comment: I haven't noted that, but now you say, I only save the image, giving it a name, in my case I save it in `.png` and he is saving passing name, format, and quality...

Comment: I don't think passing the fixed extension is a good idea,  especially if variable extension named images will be used as an input. That could possibly be one reason for the error

Comment: This happens me to not read at all. The problem is that he is trying to save an RGBA into a JPEG image, which doesn't support alpha.